# Backing up oracle to TAPE

Tags: backup, oracle, tape

our Oracle database has grown very large as of late ~= 400 - 500 GB and saving to filesystem is not scalable anymore to us. We are looking at using RMAN to backup to tape (directly, not to fs then tape).

Anyone can shed a light on this please?

OS is Enterprise Linux (Redhat/Centos), and 11g oracle.

EDIT:
I'm looking at a way of using RMAN in tandem with linux commands to achieve this, as the power-that-be wants a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could consult the [11g backup and recovery user guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/toc.htm) . Oracle RMAN does backups, but in order to backup to tape you use a Media Manager - a backup to tape product. For example, Oracle has Oracle Secure Backup that integrates with RMAN and has a free version if you have only one server and one tape device ([details are here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/secure-backup/index.html)). Finally, both RMAN and Oracle Secure Backup can be managed from the same GUI -  Enterprise Manager (Database Control and Grid Control).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Ofir Manor said, popular enterprise backup programs like HP Data Protector or Veritas Netbackup can integrate with RMAN.  Sometimes a separate license must be purchased; check with your vendor.